# How to make a custom window resizable from all sides

Tags: cocoa, subclass, nswindow, nsborderlesswindowmask

How can I make an NSWindow subclass resizable from all sides, even if using NSBorderlessWindowMask ?

Comment: Asking and answering as it was found elsewhere, but in the comments of a question with an answer accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include NSResizableWindowMask in the styleMask argument of

```
initWithContentRect: contentRect
          styleMask:(NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
    backing: bufferingType
      defer: flag
```

Comment: But that will just allow you to resize the window using the standard resize control, not *from all sides* as your original question states, right?

Comment: I thought so too. On the contrary since lion it gives the resize function from edges.